# Multiples statements where clause with differents values in Sql using JPA

Tags: sql, where-clause, hibernate-native-query

Hi guys I´m doing a native query for my project using JPA, but i don´t know how can I do a type of if and else
in a where clause, my ?0 can be 4 values: 10,20,30 and 40, when ?0 is 10, 20, 30 I should use CI.QTD <=
and when  ?0 is 40, the condition should be >= . How can I do this?

Follow my code with one condition:

```
SELECT rownum AS id, 
       x.* 
FROM   ( 
                SELECT   ci.text, 
                         ci.lenght 
                FROM     ci_table CI

                WHERE    (?0 IS NULL OR ci.qtd <= ?0) 

                GROUP BY ci.text, 
                         ci.lenght 
                ORDER BY ci.text) x , 
       nativequery = true);
```

ADD THE QUERY AFTER THE ADJUSTMENT:

```
@Query(value =
            "SELECT rownum as ID, X.* FROM (SELECT " +
                    " CI.PARAM1  " +
                    " CI.PARAM2,  " +
                    " CI.PARAM3,         " +
                    " CI.PARAM4, " +
                    " CI.PARAM5" +
                    " FROM    " +
                    " CM_PARAMS CI " +
                    " WHERE  " +
                    " (?1 is null or CI.PARAM6 = ?1) " +
                    " AND (?2 is null or CI.PARAM7 = ?2) " +
                    " AND (?3 is null or CI.PARAM8 = ?3) " +
                    " AND (?4 is null or CI.PARAM9 = ?4) " +
                    " AND (?5 is null or CI.PARAM10 = ?5) " +
                    " AND (?6 is null or CI.PARAM11 = ?6) " +
                    " AND (?7 is null or CI.PARAM12 = ?7) " +
                    " AND (?8 is null or CI.PARAM13 = ?8) " +
                    " AND (CASE WHEN ?9 >30 THEN CI.PARAM14 > 30  " +
                    "  CASE WHEN ?9 <31 THEN CI.PARAM15 <= ?9 END) = 1 " +
                    " GROUP BY " +
                    " CI.PARAM1,  " +
                    " CI.PARAM2,  " +
                    " CI.PARAM3,         " +
                    " CI.PARAM4, " +
                    " CI.PARAM5" +
                    " ORDER BY  " +
                    " CI.PARAM1 ASC) X " , nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: Use `case statement`

Comment: case _expression_...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT rownum AS id, 
       x.* 
FROM   ( 
                SELECT   ci.text, 
                         ci.lenght
                FROM     ci_table CI

                WHERE (CASE WHEN ?0 IN (10,20,30) THEN CI.QTD <= ?0
                      WHEN ?0 = 40 THEN CI.QTD > ?0 END) = 1

                GROUP BY ci.text, 
                         ci.lenght 
                ORDER BY ci.text) x , 
       nativequery = true);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer my question. I´m trying using:  AND (?8 is null or CI.TEST= ?8) 
                    AND (CASE WHEN ?9 >30 THEN CI.QTD > 30 
                    CASE WHEN ?9 <31 THEN CI.QTD <= ?9 END)  and appears this error : ORA-00905: missing keyword. Can you help?

Comment: Which DB is this query fired on? Also, please paste your whole query.

Comment: I'm using Oracle Database,  I add here the actual code. Thanks again.

Comment: check my edited answer. Added `= 1` after the `END`. Try making this change in your query and let me know.

Comment: Same error message. Did you saw the whole query in the post? org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet  --- ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: Oh.. got it.. You have an additional keyword 'CASE' written. Remove the 2nd case. Check my edited answer.
So, it should be something like.. `CASE WHEN THEN.... WHEN THEN... END`

Comment: Not yet, I'm trying here.

Comment: Hi @Mayank Porwal thanks for your time, I read and realized that what I wanted is not possible, at least not the way I'm trying to do it, so I preferred to tweak it in java.